# Подводные камни взятия адреса элемента std::vector вместо использования data()

Tags: c++, указатели, vector

У меня есть вектор байтов `std::vector<char>`. Я хочу передать его данные функции `send` из Windows Sockets API. Первым пришло в голову сделать так:

```cpp
std::vector<char> data;
// На этом моменте вектор заполняется данными
send(socket, data.data(), data.size(), 0);
```

Однако т.к. я использую старый стандарт C++ (Visual studio 2008 SP1), я не могу использовать метод `data()`, его просто нет. Тогда я прибегаю к этому:

```cpp
std::vector<char> data;
// На этом моменте вектор заполняется данными
send(socket, &data[0], data.size(), 0);
```

Я провёл пару "экспериментов", создавая векторы разной длины, заполняя их данными, а потом получая эти данные таким же способом (т.е. исключительно через указатель и его смещения) и никаких ошибок не возникло. На основании этого я предполагаю, что такой способ передачи данных вектора в функцию `send` возможен и безопасен. Но всё же, на мой взгляд, такой способ выглядит "криво", а всё, что выглядит "криво", по моему опыту таит в себе ряд подводных камней (т.е. возможностей небезопасного поведения программы в какой-либо ситуации).

Отсюда вопрос: **безопасно ли передавать данные вектора `std::vector<char> data` в функцию `send` таким `&data[0]` способом и в каких случаях это может привести к чему-то плохому (UB, исключения и т.д.)?**

P.S. Прошу не советовать использовать более новый стандарт языка. Это никаким образом не возможно для меня.

Comment: Даже в C++98 метод .data был. Следовательно, вы имеете дело с чем-то нестандартным. А раз оно у вас нестандартное, никто вам ничего хорошего не посоветует (вы даже о компиляторе ничего не сказали).

Comment: @gbg, сказал же вроде. VS2008 SP1. Компилятор встроенный. Или это неоднозначно определяет компилятор? Я сам удивлён тем, что у меня не оказалось метода `data()`, т.к. согласно документации он должен быть. Но у меня нет ничего нестандартного. Только VS. Возможно ли, что именно в Visual C++ убрали этот метод?

Comment: @gbg, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485519/11790859 тут пишут, что метод добавили только с 11 стандарта.

Comment: @V-Mor, всё нормально... не было его в том стандарте... на cppreference ошибка вот *@ gbg* и решил докопаться не посмотрев черновики... но вообще старые версии msvc известны тем, что они часто кладут болт на стагндарт...

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, все верно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще-то да, вроде бы безопасно.

Насколько я помню, даже в старом стандарте было положение, что данные в векторе расположены одним массивом (это не было закреплено de jure в стандарте для `string`, но de facto работало и там).

**Update**

Добавляю из комментариев:

- `&data[0]` таки UB если size()==0
- стоит помнить, что изменение размера/емкости вектора может делать указатели на его элементы невалидными

Comment: Стоит сделать оговорку о поведении в случае пустого массива. ` &data[0]` таки UB если `size()==0`, в отличии от `data.data()`.

Comment: а ещё стоит помнить, что любое изменение размера вектора делает указатели на его элементы невалидным...

Comment: Только не размера, а capacity.